# JavaScript works in JSFiddle, but not on its own

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, css

I don't know what is happening in this code :/. The code is right, I even attached the jQuery library file too, but still it doesn't work properly. I want to apply a class for the selected `li` and not the rest.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            a.active {
                background-color:yellow;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
             $('li a').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('a').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
              });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#1">Photography</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Web</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">Print</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rq9UB/

Comment: People don't like to be shouted on..

Comment: READ: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: You may put your js script at the end of the page to ensure dom is already loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```

I added a [**ready()**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function: *a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.*

What was happening is that when jQuery was looking for those elements to attach the click handler they were not loaded yet so `$('li a')` is a empty.

Another alternative is to put your script in just before the closing of the body tag.

Comment: You forgot to define the function()

Comment: Your script isn't valid, you need to be passing a function reference to `ready`, so should be: `.ready(function() { ...` Then the wording here - "when jQuery was looking for those elements in the click handler they were not loaded yet." - is incorrect. It's not in the click handler because the click handler never exists; the elements can't be found when it's trying to find them to create the event handler.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, good point! Corrected to `to attach the click handler `

Comment: @Sergio thank you :)... its working ..! is thr is any alternative way available without using jquery lib file ?

Comment: @Munna, Happy I could help! Do you mean a plain javascript solution? yes, just it takes more code. Plain javascript is faster but more code to write.

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage of [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('li a').click(function(e)
    {
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    })
})
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rq9UB/506/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try following, the difference is that is does not wait for dom ready, as you see dom is already loaded before the script. Also adding the scripts at the end of the pages is considered to be good practice.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a.active {
            background-color:yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#1">Photography</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2">Web</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3">Print</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script>
         $('li a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('a').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
          });
    </script>
</body>
```